# Drag drop widgets in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I like Ext JS and have started using it but soon I ran into a problem with drag/drop. I have a custom widget which extends Ext.Component and this widget displays a text box and a button. I have added this widget in an absolute layout. I want to enable drag/drop for this widget so that I can freely move this widget in the panel.

I see examples on Ext JS websites but they mostly deal with divs and not at a widget level.

How do I achieve this at a widget level and not at a div level?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can anybody please give me a pointer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every component in ExtJs extends Ext.Base , and Ext.AbstractComponet. This Class has draggable method attached, so if you have custom component witch extends Ext.Component, you can access this [method.](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-draggable)

```
 draggable:true
```

Also, show your code when asking specific question, this way it's easier to get an answer!
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is an example, I have a Panel. The panel contains set set of form fields. Now I want to drag the Panel along with form fields. The panel is draggable with draggable=true only if it has title bar otherwise not. So how can I achieve it? Please provide some pointers.